# Combine two saved rockets in KSP Mac

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program on the Mac, is there any way to load two saved rockets into one workspace in the Assembly Building? For example, I want to load the Heavy Orbiter with the Kerbal X in order to launch in to the Mun. How can I do this?

Comment: I have a feeling you have to save one of them as a sub-assembly and then open the other.

Comment: Could you please explain that in the form of an answer?

Comment: I'm at work right now, so can't provide a proper answer.  I need to test the solution first.

Comment: Does the Mac version of KSP have any relevant differences such that this question requires the [[tag:os-x]] tag?

Comment: Sorry, @vedantchandra, I didn't get a chance to test this out and now I'm away for the long weekend.  Just go ahead and see if what I suggested works, and if so, problem solved.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, because I cannot mod the mac version

Comment: @vedantchandra you don't need mods in order to do what you want to do, it's a built in feature now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [version 0.22](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Version_history#v0.22), this is possible with the newly-implemented subassemblies.

In *Kerbal Space Program*, each saved assembly (rocket, plane or subassembly for either) is stored as a `.craft` file in a subdirectory of the save folder (`{KSP root}/saves/{name of save}/`):

- `Ships/SPH` for *Space Plane Hangar* constructions
- `Ships/VAB` for *Vehicle Assembly Building* constructions
- `subassemblies/SPH` and `subassemblies/VAB` for the subassemblies respectivley.

Subassemblies and normal vessels have *almost no differences*. There is, usually, no need to change anything about the save files - merely move them from one directory to the other.

However, a subassembly requires a *free attachment node* at the *root part*. You need to make sure (either through save editing or through in-game editing and saving) that the *root part* (that is, the part that you *first placed* and then connected everything else to) has *at least one free attachment node.