# lv909 and nuclear engines flaming out?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I launched a ship into orbit around the sun and got to the point that I have to start using my small engines but when I decouple the previous poodle engine, all four of my lv909/nuclear engines die: "oxidizer deprived", flameout.

Any ideas why this happened?

[craft](http://pastebin.com/U8G67xPT)

Comment: Could you upload the relevant `*.craft` file (see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148780) how to locate it.)? This seems like an error with your staging or tweakables.

Comment: of course but upload to where?

Comment: Since they're plaintext, you can just copy the content of the file and either use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), or even just put it in quote formatting in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using [jet fuselage parts](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Mk1_Fuselage_-_Jet_Fuel) instead of rocket fuel tanks.  Jet fuel is just that: just the fuel and no oxidizer.  Chemical rocket engines work by performing a controlled reduction-oxidation (redox) reaction.  When this reaction is energetic, it's communally referred to as burning.

You need both a reduction agent a.k.a. a fuel, and an oxidizing agent, a.k.a. an oxidizer.  If we look at a common camp fire, we can easily see that the fuel is the wood that's being burned, but less obvious is that the oxidizer is atmospheric oxygen.  Well, there's no atmosphere in space, so you have to bring your oxidizer with you, most commonly liquid oxygen.

Comment: of course, but no, all four engines are attached to liquid fuel tanks with oxidizer. it was the first thing I checked.

Comment: If you haven't used the jet fuselages anywhere in your rocket, my only other explanation is that you changed the load of oxidizer in the VAB or disabled oxidizer flow from one of your tanks.

Comment: I did manually change oxidizer from one of my other tanks in the early stages as I was refueling on a satellite near Mun but I didn't touch any of these four tanks. How would I disable oxidizer flow in the first place? (all tanks have full oxidizer/liquid fuel before flaming out)

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAH that's what it was. Damn it. I locked the engines when I was transferring fuel and left them locked. How could I be this stupid...ok thanks for the help!